# Customized select element options in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, I have a select element

```
<select ng-model="event" ng-options="event as event.name for event in events">
   <option value="">Select event</option>
</select>
```

that displays each option as

```
event.name
```

but I'd like to display each as

```
event.name | event.date
```

**demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/zYtFF/

Help much appreciated.

Comment: maybe something like `ng-options="event as my_event_formatting_function(event) for event in events"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to format the display portion of your text:

```
ng-options="event as event.name+' | '+event.date for event in events"
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YhJqb/1/